# Issue in serializing a vector of deques using Boost

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

How do I serialize a vector of deques using Boost Serialization library.

Currently, I have the following code for this purpose:

```
#include <boost/serialization/deque.hpp> //in includes

Item1(6128, std::deque<float> ()), //constructor initializations
Item2(6128, std::deque<float> ()),
Item3(6128,std::deque<int> ()),
Item4(6128,std::deque<int> ()),

private:
 friend class boost::serialization::access;
 template <typename Archive>
 void
serialize(Archive &ar,
    const unsigned int /*file_version*/)
{

for (unsigned i = 0; i < Item1.size(); ++i)
{ar & Item1[i];}
for (unsigned i = 0; i < Item2.size(); ++i)
{ar & Item2[i];}
for (unsigned i = 0; i < Item3.size(); ++i)
{ar & Item3[i];}
for (unsigned i = 0; i < Item4.size(); ++i)
{ar & Item4[i];}

}

std::vector< std::deque<float> > Item1, Item2;
std::vector< std::deque<int> > Item3, Item4;
```

This code compiles and runs fine. However, the values I store are different from the ones I loaded while serializing. Am I doing something wrong? Is this the right method to serialize a vector of deques?

Your feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are not serializing the size of Item1...Item4

I suggest you use STL container serialization directly:

1. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#stl
2. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#models

e.g.

```
ar & Item1;
ar & Item2;
ar & Item3;
ar & Item4;
```

#### <sub>*Alternatively you could split into Load/Save methods and save / load the container size explicitely.*</sub>

```
template<class Archive>
void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const
{
    ar  & Item1.size();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Item1.size(); ++i)
        {ar & Item1[i];}

    ar  & Item2.size();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Item2.size(); ++i)
        {ar & Item2[i];}

    // etc...
}
template<class Archive>
void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    size_t size;
    ar & size;
    Item1.resize(size);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Item1.size(); ++i)
        {ar & Item1[i];}

    ar & size;
    Item2.resize(size);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Item2.size(); ++i)
        {ar & Item2[i];}

    // etc...
}
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
```

Comment: Do you mean this:-
`
    private:
     friend class boost::serialization::access;
     template <typename Archive>
     void
    serialize(Archive &ar,
        const unsigned int /*file_version*/)
    {
    ar & Item1 & Item2 & Item3 & Item4;
    }
`
I did try this first but this doesn't work either for vector of deques.

Comment: Sorry, I can't read that. Also, I have updated the question in case you needed alternatives

Comment: I apologize for that mess. I'm trying to get the code down properly in comments but it isn't getting through right in the comments box. give me a minute.

Comment: @mahajan_l33t: You can just edit the question or ... read my response :). Did you include `<boost/serialization/vector.hpp>`?